# Как изменить скорость смены спрайтов canvas html5

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, 2d

Моя задача сделать анимацию из спрайтов, они разбиты по на разные png, и я сделал чтобы спрайты менялись, но скорость смены этих спрайтов бешеная. Подскажите как изменить скорость смены спрайтов.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = window.screen.width;
canvas.height = window.screen.height;

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var sprite = new Image();
sprite.src = './png/male/Walk (1).png';

/** Массив **/
var image_male = [
  './png/male/Walk (1).png',
  './png/male/Walk (2).png',
  './png/male/Walk (3).png',
  './png/male/Walk (4).png',
  './png/male/Walk (5).png',
  './png/male/Walk (6).png',
  './png/male/Walk (7).png',
  './png/male/Walk (8).png',
  './png/male/Walk (9).png',
  './png/male/Walk (10).png'
]

var current_sprite_male = 0;

/** Отрисовка **/
function drawMale() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.drawImage(sprite, 10, 10, 70, 120);
  sprite.src = image_male[current_sprite_male];

  current_sprite_male += 1;

  if (current_sprite_male == 9) {
    current_sprite_male = 0;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(drawMale);
}

drawMale();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var cx = canvas.width / 2;
var cy = canvas.height / 2;
var r = canvas.width / 2;
var last = new Date();
var index = 0;

function draw() {
  var now = new Date();
  var elapsed = now - last;
  if (elapsed >= 1000) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(cx, cy);
    var x = cx + r * Math.cos(index / 180 * Math.PI);
    var y = cy + r * Math.sin(index / 180 * Math.PI);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.stroke();
    index++;
    last = now;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое это действительно то что нужно.